# Validar radio button con javascript

Tags: javascript, validación, radiobutton

tengo un formulario donde tengo que validar el nombre, el horario si es de mañana o tardes y aceptar las normas del registro.

Con lo que tengo problemas, es el tema del horario, tengo dos radio buttons pero no consigo validar que uno de los dos este seleccionado.

```js
function validar(){
        
        valor = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
        
        if( valor == null || valor.length == 0) {
          alert('Error, rellena el campo nombre');
        return false;
        }
        
        
        
        
        if(!registro.checked ){
          alert('Debe aceptar el registro');
          return false;
        }
}
```

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
    <form id="formulario" onsubmit="validar()">
          <label>Nombre: </label><br>
          <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
    
          <br><br>
    
          <label>Horario:</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="horario" value="mañana"><label>Mañana</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" id="horario" value="tarde"><label>Tarde</label>
    
            <br><br>
    
          <label>Aceptar las normas de registro:</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="registro" value="registro" id="registro">
    <br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para agrupar radio inputs se agrupan por el atributo name, en cuanto a obtener si hay algún radio input checqueado, se ha de comprobar de la siguiente manera:

> document.querySelector('input[name="horario"]:checked')

Con el selector se obtiene todos los input con nombre `horario` que estén checked === true.

```js
// bindamos al evento submit del elemento formulario la función de validación
document.getElementById("formulario").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    let hasError = false;
    valor = document.getElementById('nombre').value;

    if( valor == null || valor.length == 0) {
      alert('Error, rellena el campo nombre');
      hasError = true;
    }

    // obtenemos todos los input radio del grupo horario que esten chequeados
    // si no hay ninguno lanzamos alerta
    if(!document.querySelector('input[name="horario"]:checked')) {
      alert('Error, rellena el campo horario');
      hasError = true;
      }

    if(!registro.checked ){
      alert('Debe aceptar el registro');
      hasError = true;
    }
    
    // si hay algún error no efectuamos la acción submit del form
    if(hasError) event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form id="formulario">
      <label>Nombre: </label><br>
      <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">

      <br><br>

      <label>Horario:</label><br>
          <input type="radio" name="horario" value="mañana"><label>Mañana</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="horario" value="tarde"><label>Tarde</label>

        <br><br>

      <label>Aceptar las normas de registro:</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="registro" value="registro" id="registro">
<br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente, justo lo que buscaba :)))

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Emplearemos este selector
    document.querySelector('input[name="horario"]:checked')
    checkProvider();
    function checkProvider()
    {
       let check = document.querySelector('input[name="provider"]:checked')
       if(check !== null) console.log('Provider', check);
       else console.log('Favor seleccione el proveedor');
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Y por cierto, ¿en qué difiere tu respuesta con la [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217372) (más completa)?